# Change index.html nginx kubernetes deployment

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have this deployment:

[image]

I was able to edit the index page at one of my pods, but how can I commit it to the deployment image? So when I scale the application all new pods will have the same image with index edited.

Answer (score 5):

It's worked for me

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - containerPort: 80
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
        name: nginx-conf
        subPath: index.html
  volumes:
    - name: nginx-conf
      configMap:
        name: nginx-index-html-configmap
```

And simple configmap with:

```
data:
<html></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a new image with the updated index.html, and then use this new image on your deployments.

If you want index.html to be easily modifiable, then

1. Create a new image without the index.html file
2. Store the contents of index.html in a configMap
3. Volume mount the configMap (as explained [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#configmap)) onto the path where you want index.html to be mounted

Then, whenever you want to update the index.html, you just have to update the ConfigMap and wait for a few minutes. Kubernetes will take care of syncing the updated index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49911940/4673027) and this [readme](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/https-nginx/README.md)

One can create a configMap with the following command

```
kubectl create configmap nginx-index-html-configmap --from-file=index.html -o yaml --dry-run
```

And then add this cm as a volumeMount in k8s deployment object.

Answer (score 0):

Use init container for any preprocessing or as stated above change docker image accordingly before using it.