# How to create Deployment on nginx with custom text in index.html?

Tags: kubernetes, web-deployment, configmap

How to create in kubernetes deployment on nginx which will create custom index.html?

is there a way how to create custom index.hmtl with a text: "welcome to the lab"?
Or its not possible to do that? Or I should use ConfigmaP? Thank you for your time:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create custom `index.hmtl` with a text `"welcome to the lab"`, you need to build your own docker image and then by using that image you can create the kubernetes deployment.

```
containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

here, in the manifest you are giving the specification of the container, where you used `nginx` image and you can not change the image as you have no access of the `dockerfile` by which that image were created.

In your `deployment` manifest you give two specification, in outer specification you give the `replicas` which means how many replica of your application need to run. Another specification is the container specification, here you give your application `image` which can be your own `image` or others image like `nginx`, now the when the deployment create successfully and also the pods then you will only see the things that was defined in your used application image. So, you if you want different things than you need different image containing your desired outputs.

Comment: so as i understood i should use this method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49904784/change-index-html-nginx-kubernetes-deployment

Answer (score 1):

here you are using the build-in docker image for `nginx`. and you can't produce custom html as you are using the pre-build docker image. even you can't change anything in nginx server. as this one is already build in docker and k8s is just pulling that image from docker and run it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49904784/change-index-html-nginx-kubernetes-deployment so i can do that only in a such way - thank you